Velocity of a body after rising out of a ideal liquid
Suppose you have a cube of volume $S m^3$ and you submerge the lower edge of the cube to a height $h$ below the surface of the liquid. $h>S$ i.e the cube is completely submerged.
Now, once you release the cube from rest, how would you calculate it's velocity at the moment when buoyant force equals to zero (i.e. the cube is out of the liquid)
Density of the cube < Density of the liquid
Liquid is ideal: No surface tension/drag force/viscosity element.
Now I understand there will be three things that will happen during the course of the block's journey.

Buoyant force provides a constant acc. till the upper surface of the block is just out of the liquid.
Buoyant force becomes variable just after the upper surface of the block comes out of the liquid.
Buoyant force stops providing upward acc., when the block reaches the equilibrium position it would have been in if, it was left to just float on the liquid.

Although this is completely irrelevant to what I am studying in my undergrad classes I just wonder how do we approach a problem like this?
I tried to approach the problem using simply Newton's law's of motion it but got stuck in a loop in part "2)".
Loop: Cube has acquired some velocity till the moment (2), so the height below the surface of the liquid will be a function of velocity. To make a function for the buoyant force, it'd most definitely have height below the surface of the liquid as a variable. But, velocity will a function of the buoyant force. All in all to form a function for buoyant force there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way.
Am I wrong or some assumption would have to be made like work down by buoyant force in part (2), (3) is negligible hence, not considering it's effect on the already acquired velocity of the object.

The upward force is not constant. It depends on the depth of the object. You might think about how pressure varies with depth.

Calculate the force as a function of displacement from the equilibrium position and you'll find the motion is simple harmonic.

I think the "loop" you're describing can be resolved once you know how to solve differential equations.

@MichaelSeifert I do know how to solve differential equations!! I just don't have a idea to build upon and make the differential equation for the 'loop' I mentioned. Could you give me just a hint from where I would be able to form the equation.
I know the velocity the object has just before the buoyant force becomes variable.

Roughly speaking you'd have an equation of the form $$ m \frac{dv}{dt} = f(v) $$ where $f(v)$ is the hypothetical function for the instantaneous force as a function of the velocity;  or $$ m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = f(\dot{x}, x)$$ if this function needs to depend on position as well. Once you had this ODE, you could in principle solve it given an initial position and velocity. (I don't know off the top of my head what the function $f$ would be, unfortunately.)

f  is the thing I am struggling with
